# Regex to convert markdown to html

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, regexp-replace

My goal is to take a markdown text and create the necessary bold/italic/underline html tags.
Looked around for answers, got some inspiration but I'm still stuck.

I have the following typescript code, the regex matches the expression including the double asterisk:

```js
var text = 'My **bold\n\n** text.\n'
var bold = /(?=\*\*)((.|\n)*)(?<=\*\*)/gm
var html = text.replace(bold, '<strong>$1</strong>');   
console.log(html)
```

Now the result of this is : My <\strong>** bold\n\n **<\strong> text.
Everything is great aside from the leftover double asterisk.
I also tried to remove them in a later 'replace' statement, but this creates further issues.

How can I ensure they are removed properly?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using one of the many existing markdown libraries, like [Marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your pattern `(?=\*\*)((.|\n)*)(?<=\*\*)` you *assert* (not match) with `(?=\*\*)` that there is `**` directly to the right.

Then directly after that, you *capture* the `**` using `((.|\n)*)` so then it becomes part of the match.

Then at the end you *assert* again with `(?<=\*\*)` that there is `**` directly to the left, but `((.|\n)*)` has already matched it.

This way so you will end up with all the `**` in the match.

You don't need lookarounds at all, as you are already using a capture group.

In Javascript you could match the `**` on the left and right and capture any character in a capture group:

```
\*\*([^]*?)\*\*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BPiOya/1)

**But** I would suggest using a dedicated parser to parse markdown instead of using a regex.

Comment: Too new to upvote apparently (: 
I was wondering which parsers would you suggest?
Working mainly with typescript.

Comment: @AntonOlshanetsky On stackoverflow you can mark answers as accepted by clicking the grey checkmark on the left, you can upvote answers from 15 reputation points. I have not used a specific markdown parser for Typescript, but you will have a lot of results running a google search (that is what I would do at least :-))

Comment: After initially accepting Gustavo's answer, I ran more tests and came to the conclusion this solution actually works far better. Thank you ~ switching my acceptance!

Answer (score 0):

Just make another call to `replaceAll` removing the `**` with and empty string.

```js
var text = 'My **bold\n\n** text.\n'
var bold = /(?=\*\*)((.|\n)*)(?<=\*\*)/gm
var html = text.replace(bold, '<strong>$1</strong>');
html = html.replaceAll(/\*\*/gm,'');
console.log(html)
```